# Node express passport (JWT) - callback after auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, jwt

I have authentication working with passport JWT, but I am having difficulty running a callback function/response, *only if* a user is authenticated. How can this be done?

In my routes:

```
import express from 'express';
import passport from '../../config/passport';
import memberInfoCtrl from '../controllers/memberInfo';

const router = express.Router();

router.route('/members')
  .get(membersCtrl.tokenCheck, passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), membersCtrl.doSomethingElse);

export default router;
```

I want `membersCtrl.doSomethingElse` to be run if authentication is successful.

Here is my tokenCheck function:

```
function tokenCheck(req, res, next) {
  const token = getToken(req.headers);
  if (token) {
    const decoded = jwt.decode(token, config.secret);
    User.findOne({
      email: decoded.email
    }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(403).send({
          success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'
        });
      }
      // res.json({ success: true, msg: 'Welcome to the member area!' });
      return next();
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({ success: false, msg: 'No token provided.' });
  }
}
```

Using `res.json` in `tokenCheck` works fine, but the `doSomethingElse` function is not getting called afterwards.

I thought it's because we send a response like this:

`res.json({ success: true, msg: 'Welcome to the member area!' });`

Replacing the `res.json` with `return next();` returns the error:

`Error: Unknown authentication strategy \"jwt\"`

Why does this happen - how can I check for authentication before executing another function, for the same route?

I'm sure it's something silly i'm missing. Any help is appreciated!

Here is part of my main express script that initialises passport:

```
import passport from 'passport';
...
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use('/api', routes);
...
```

Passport config:

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
import User from '../server/models/user';
import config from './env';

module.exports = (passport) => {
  const opts = {};
  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwtPayload, done) => {
    User.findOne({ id: jwtPayload.id }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err, false);
      }
      if (user) {
        done(null, user);
      } else {
        done(null, false);
      }
    });
  }));
};
```

Comment: No-one able to help? I am getting a headache :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your general approach is correct. To protect a route depending on some conditions write a custom middleware calling `next()` if those conditions are fulfilled.

But in your case this is not necessary as this is what `passport-jwt` does. So assuming that you configured [`passport`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) and [`passport-jwt`](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt) correctly all you need to write is this:

```
router.route('/members')
    .get(passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), membersCtrl.doSomethingElse);
```

`passport-jwt` will extract the JWT from the request and verify it against your provided secret or key. Afterwards it will use passport's `verify` callback to populate `req.user` ([source](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt/blob/33639a7414cd48df8101159a41518ad2b32b12fd/lib/strategy.js#L81)).

Additionally: Yes after using `res.json()` a response is sent which is why your passport middleware and anything beyond is not reached in that case.

Regarding your error `Error: Unknown authentication strategy \"jwt\"`: This usually happens if you did not configure your passport authentication correctly. If you include it in your question I will take a look at it and extend my answer accordingly.

**Update:** Your code looks good to me except one thing: You did not specify the `jwtFromRequest` attribute in your `passport-jwt` options which is mandatory. Or did you by any chance forget to invoke your passport config?

**Update 2:** Further clarification regarding my comment below:
 1.) Import your ES6 passport config module (*where you added the `jwtFromRequest` option*) in your main express script and invoke it:

```
import passport from 'passport';
import passportConfig from 'path/to/passport/config';
...
app.use(passport.initialize());
passportConfig(passport);
...
```

2.) Make sure to remove your `tokenCheck` function, you don't need it. See the first part of this answer.

**Update 3:** 'Unauthorized' is great because it means that you are successfully protecting your `/members` route now. To implement a token-based authentication you now need an additional route `/authenticate` where users can request access to your web service e.g. by providing credentials (your route will verify these credentials and respond with a JWT which must be signed with the same secret you are using for `passport-jwt` - otherwise `passport-jwt` will not be able to verify the token signature later).

But this goes beyond the scope of this question. There should be many resources out there covering this. You can for example implement an `/authenticate` route using [`jsonwebtoken`](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) which is shown in [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens) (they are not using `passport` at all but use `jsonwebtoken` for token creation *and* validation).

**Note:** If you are also implementing a client you have to include some additional logic there to store the JWT and to include it in your requests to the express app.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, very helpful. I've included more details in my question. I have a modular ES6 approach. It seems that maybe passport isn't initialised in my routes module or something, because of the 'unknown strategy' error that is called on the route?

Comment: The passport instance is implemented as a singleton, so invoking your configuration module once with `passport` as parameter should work application wide...

Comment: What do you mean by configuration module - the passport config? I'm doing this at the moment: `app.use(passport.initialize());`

Comment: I've included `jwtFromRequest`, but same issue. The issue only occurs when I replace `res.json()` with `return next()`, in the `tokenCheck` function. Using `res.json` works fine, but I need to run middlware after `tokenCheck`.

Comment: By configuration module I mean the ES6 module in your question which configures `passport-jwt`. You have to import and invoke the exported function in your main express script (this is *not* done by `app.use(passport.initialize());`). And like I wrote in my answer, you should remove your `tokenCheck` function, it is redundant as it does the same as `passport.authenticate('jwt', ...)` (so you are verifying your token twice).

Comment: Thanks again Jonas, really appreciate your help. Definitely getting somewhere. With the latest config updates you suggested, I am now getting a simple 'Unauthorized' response from passport when I ping an endpoint. So the 'unknown strategy' error is gone now, but seems that whatever I pass into the headers/body, passport returns 'unauthorized' response. Any ideas? (`tokenCheck` is removed as well now)

Comment: No problem Tony, always happy to help. :-) I updated my answer again.

Comment: "Afterwards it will use passport's verify callback to populate req.user". That part is gold :) Seems simple but it's actually not quite well documented by Passport.